# Result is not appearing when filtering the cache data: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **What is it about ?**

Filtering the `cache` data using two approaches. Below is the code.

**Attempt : 1**

```
$Categories = \Cache::rememberForever('Categories', function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
});
$Category = $Categories->where('CategoryID', $request->input('CategoryID'));
```

**Attempt : 2**

```
$Categories = \Cache::rememberForever('Categories', function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
});
foreach($Categories as $Category) {
    if($Category->CategoryID == $request->input('CategoryID')) {
        $Category->Category = $request->input('Category');
        $Category->IsActive =  $request->input('IsActive') == "on" ? 1 : 0;
        $Category->save();
        \Cache::forget('Categories');
        return Redirect('Categories-List');
    }
}
```

### **Question:**

While using Approach : 1, results are always null, where as while using Approach : 2, there is no Problem. Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the return type for

```
$Category = $Categories->where('CategoryID', $request->input('CategoryID'))
```

is collection,

try,

```
$Category = $Categories->where('CategoryID', $request->input('CategoryID'))->first();
```

Comment: `dd($Categories);` and check the object type.

Comment: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_where. its possible to use where.  please check `$Categories->count()` and `$Categories->first()` outputs

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to

### `intval($CategoryID)`

```
$Category = $Categories->where('CategoryID', intval($CategoryID));
```